# Why do I not get the JSON body in the log?

Tags: c#, json

I am using HTTPClient to send a JSON object to a REST web service, I am capturing the response but I only get the headers in the log not the JSON response in the body of the response.

The relevant code is as follows

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

 HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://example.com/api/checkout", new StringContent(transaction.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

log.Info("response is " + response);
```

How can I capture the JSON response from the body in the response?

Comment: By reading it from the response object (e.g. `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the body from the content stream

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: is there no way of reading it into a JObject directly? I need to get it is string and then serialize it?

Comment: @MattDouhan Why would something like `JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())` be a problem for you?

Comment: @MattDouhan 1st `HttpResponseMessage` is not a `string`. 2nd read the `string` and then parse your `string` to and `JObject` like Kirk Larkin said

Answer (score 0):

Response is the returned object which includes multiple properties like headers or httpcontext.

You need to read the the content property into the desired type for example:

```
var jsonObj = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

You can also skip the ReadAsStringAsync() and do the read directly using:

```
response.content.ReasAsSync<object>();
```